# Blu-ray software options for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, vlc-media-player, development, blu-ray, playback

Ok, so Apple has not official supported Blu-ray playback in Mac OS X yet.  Has anyone developed any Blu-ray playback software for Mac OS X?  I have seen Toast and a few others that are able to write to Blu-ray discs, but no simple playback apps.  Are there really no options for this right now?

Decent discussion going on in the apple forums:
http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2032714&tstart=0

Nothing else besides VLC?  VLC has recently voiced concern over the development of the os x version. Check it out: http://www.macrumors.com/2009/12/17/videolan-considering-options-for-vlc-as-mac-developers-disappear/

Answer (score 2):

[VLC](http://videolan.org) can play Bluray files, but not ones with copy-protection, which makes this of limited use..

Answer (score 2):

The only way to play blu-ray movies in OSX is with VLC as previously mentioned. Although there is no way to play blu-ray movies with HDCP at all as of yet. If you wish to play one properly you will need to boot into Windows via boot camp.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://www.tuaw.com/2009/04/09/second-generation-blu-ray-ships-for-mac/) suggests that you can't, though more options may have popped up since it was written (April).